# The injection of direct image sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ be a smooth holomorphic fibration between K\"ahler manifolds and $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. Let $m$ be a positive integer. We denote by $E:=f_*\mathcal{O}_X(mK_{X/Y}+L)$. We know that for a generic point $y\in Y$, $E_y=H^0(X_y,mK_{X_y}+L|_{X_y})$. My question is, do we have the injection $E_y\longrightarrow H^0(X_y,mK_{X_y}+L|_{X_y})$ for any point $y\in Y$? If this is not true, we further assume $E$ is locally free, do we have the injection property?

Comment: It's an isomorphism even, no?

Comment: Since $L$ is an arbitrary line bundle, what is the relevance of adding $mK_{X/Y}$? Just consider $f_*L$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an injection at every point if the base is a curve. I actually do not know the answer  if the base has higher dimension.  An easy way to see this in the one dimensional base case is the following:

Set $D := mK_{X/Y} + L$ and consider the exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(D - f^* y) \to \mathcal{O}_X(D) \to \mathcal{O}_{X_y} \left(D|_{X_y} \right) \to 0.
\end{equation*}

Pushing this forward and using projection formula yields
\begin{equation*}
0 \to \mathcal{O}_Y(-y) \otimes f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D)  \to f_* \mathcal{O}_X(D) \to H^0\left(X_y, \mathcal{O}_{X_y} \left(D|_{X_y} \right) \right) 
\end{equation*}

Note that the cokernel of the first map is exactly $k(y) \otimes f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D)$, so we get an injection
\begin{equation*}
k(y) \otimes f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D) \hookrightarrow H^0\left(X_y, \mathcal{O}_{X_y} \left(D|_{X_y} \right) \right).
\end{equation*}

To conclude the argument one should just contemplate whether this map agrees with the natural map in the question (it does).